# permission denied AWS EC2 file.save from Flask App

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, flask

I am writing an application in Flask and am deploying it in EC2. I am trying to make the user upload files in the local directory. But I get a permission denied error when The uploaded file is being saved. I am attaching the code below. pls do help me fix it. I have tried to change the folder permissions to sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www but that doesn't help. I do understand giving write permissions is bad but this for development mode and hoping to get it through 
this is the code

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
         def upload_file():
        # Get the name of the uploaded files
        uploaded_files = request.files.getlist("file[]")
        filenames = []
        for file in uploaded_files:
        # Check if the file is one of the allowed types/extensions
         if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        # Make the filename safe, remove unsupported chars
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        # Move the file form the temporal folder to the upload
        # folder we setup
        current_date = time.strftime("%x").split("/")           [0]+time.strftime("%x").split("/")[1]+time.strftime("%x").split("/")[2]
        directory = os.path.join('loadedfiles/')
        uploadedfilesdir = directory + current_date
        if not os.path.exists(uploadedfilesdir):
            os.makedirs(uploadedfilesdir)
        file.save(os.path.join(uploadedfilesdir, filename)) 
        # Save the filename into a list, we'll use it later
        filenames.append(filename)
        # Redirect the user to the uploaded_file route, which
        # will basicaly show on the browser the uploaded file
# Load an html page with a link to each uploaded file
return render_template('upload.html', filenames=filenames)
```

Comment: it can help to change the owner & group of the upload destination folder to **www-data** (or whatever user/group the webserver is running as)

Answer (score 0):

Probably related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38998060/flask-permissions-for-file-writing/38998429?noredirect=1#comment65348759_38998429), solution to convert the relative path to an absolute path. I do not know how programs are started on EC2 but it appears that the working directory is within some Python / library directory where the executed program is not allowed to write. A fix to use absolute paths might look like so:

```
directory = os.path.join('/var/www/', 'loadedfiles/', current_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to give absolute path like instead of this

```
path = ./static/upload_folder
```

Try this

```
path = /var/www/folder/folder/static/upload_folder
```

And then don't forget to give all permissions to that folder by this command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/folder/folder/static/upload_folder
```

This works for me!

Comment: Don't use _Camel Case_ on normal text and definitely DON'T USE ALL CAPS. Edit your answer to allow me to un-vote it down.